# Difference hasClass and is

Tags: jquery

I have following html code with four classes.

**HTML**

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3 class4"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
alert($("div").hasClass(".class4")); //return false
alert($("div").is(".class4"));  //return true
```

My question is `hasClass` is used to check weather has a class named `given className`,
But here it is return false with existing class. What is difference between `is` and `hasClass` ?

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lro45zsn/1/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference in this case, but `hasClass` doesn't include the period in the selector, it takes just the classname, which is why you get the wrong result

```
$("div").hasClass("class4");  //return true
$("div").is(".class4");       //return true
```

However, `is()` accepts more than just classes, and does more internal matching, so using `hasClass` is more appropriate, and should be faster (not noticeable).

Comment: Thanks for quick answer and explaination. I accept your answer after 10 minutes. Thank you very much!!!